# Swift iOS module not being deployed to expected debug directory

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a module/framework written in Swift, intended to be used on iOS. When I try to include the framework in my app, I first notice some red "not found" hints in the build phases:

[image]

But, the project *builds* fine - the target dependency is found, so there are no compilation issues. It's just the resulting built framework - and sure enough, upon launching, I have a linker error, it can't find the image. Looking at the build log, it's looking here:

```
/Users/Craig/Projects/Fluffy/build/Debug-iphoneos/
```

Which makes sense - that's what is defined in the Build Settings for my framework:

[image]

But the copy fails, as the source framework doesn't exist:

```
PBXCp /Users/Craig/projects/Fluffy/build/Debug-iphoneos/Fluffy_iOS.framework /Users/Craig/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dcjfhcnyzkwzxiejuuxqlsgajreb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp/Frameworks/Fluffy_iOS.framework
...
error: /Users/Craig/projects/Fluffy/build/Debug-iphoneos/Fluffy_iOS.framework: No such file or directory
```

However, looking at the build log for my framework, I see that it's *actually* ending up here:

```
/Users/Craig/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fluffy-fuuewsvogdkycegheyrsabkiicxc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Fluffy_iOS.framework
```

I suppose that makes sense - DerivedData has for a while now been the default location for any built products.

And when I take a look at the *expected* build folder, there's not much, a lot of it is old, and none of it relates to the Debug configuration:

[image]

So my questions are: Why is my framework being placed in the `DerivedData` folder, when it seems to be asking in the Build Settings to be placed in the `build` folder relative to the project? Are these parameters (per-configuration build products path, etc.) consulted at all?

And, what should I do to reconcile this? How can my application know to look in the right DerivedData folder for the framework, for the right configuration (debug vs. release) in a way that is extensible and will work without me having to manually specify the absolute path to it?

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem. Have you managed to find a fix?

Comment: Nope, no luck unfortunately. :-(

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you have a workspace and is Fluffy_iOS being built in that workspace as a dependency?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Okay, so I figured out how to work around this. This assumes you have workspace and you have included the framework as a project in the workspace and you are trying to build a product from another project in the workspace which includes the framework.

What you need to do is find out where the framework is being built. It's usually some crazy directory under the `DeriveData` directory. Go to the Finder and find it for the configuration you just tried to build.

In the product target's `General` settings, under `Embedded Binaries`, drag that file into it. This should now place it in the `Project Navigator`. You should also see it in the `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` which was underneath `Embedded Binaries`.

Go to the `Project Navigator` and select the file and view it under the `File Inspector`. There, change the `Location` to `Relative to Build Products`.

In the target's `Build Settings`, for `Framework Search Paths`, add `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)` and make that recursive. Delete the entry that was automatically added when you added the framework. It will be an explicit path which has the DerivedData path in it.

Do a deep clean and delete the `DerivedData` directory for good measure.

Build.

You should now see the framework turn black and it should work properly.

Comment: Hooray! Most unclear and important: **Go to the Project Navigator and select the file and view it under the File Inspector. There, change the Location to Relative to Build Products**

Comment: What entry? "Delete the entry that was automatically added when you added the framework. "

Comment: Usually when you add a framework, Xcode will put an entry to the path for it in the Framework Search Paths. That path will be an explicit path using your path directory. That does not play well with others since they will more than likely not have your path structure (which includes your username)

Comment: Can anybody explains `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)` steps? How one should know that? Any documentation around there (hopefully, from Apple)? The build settings part along with UI setup has always been a tricky part for me...

Comment: Google is generally your friend for these types of things. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html

Comment: @Mobile Ben thank you, but my question was about something else. I don't understand why one has to do so many steps besides just `Embedded Binaries`? Editing the path, editing `Framework Search Paths`, etcetera...

Comment: You can chalk this up to the nuances of Xcode. It is possible there are other ways to do this. And bear in mind this was also from an older version of Xcode. I'm on the latest and it does seem these steps are still relevant. For example, editing the path is needed because in this case what happens is Xcode will put in a path, but it an absolute path based on your machine. So if your project has other people, they won't be able to find the framework.

Comment: @Mobile Ben btw I've been using your steps each time I add embedded framework to my apps. These is valid for both Xcode 7.3.1 and Xcode 8 beta.

Answer (score 1):

These are slightly modified steps provided by @Mobile Ben

Assume, you have the following Xcode project structure

```
-YourWorkspace
--YourFramework project
--YourApp project
```

step 1. Clear all the targets with `Cmd+Shift+K` and `Cmd+Option+Shift+K` (by choosing each of them in the Scheme selector and pressing the hotkey combination)

step 2. Select `YourFramework` project.

step 3. Choose a simulator and build (`Cmd+B`) `YourFramework` framework target

step 4: Choose `Generic iOS Device` and build (`Cmd+B`) `YourFramework` framework target

step 5: Select `YourApp` project. Press `+` in `Embedded Binaries` and choose  **the framework under YourFramework project**

step 6: now locate the just added framework in Project Navigator (on the left). In File Inspector (on the right) select location `Relative to build product`.

**NOTE:** I believe the step 6 is required b/c of some bug in Xcode. But, though, not selecting `Relative to build product` by default might be a deliberate act

**UPD#1:** Since Xcode 8.0 (8A218a), step 6 is not needed anymore - the IDE sets `Relative to Build Products` automatically.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. I didn't know where to look for File Inspector

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer which works perfectly on Simulator. On device you will get dyld library not found error and a crash.

Here is the solution for that:

In the project that depends on this framework:
   Under the build settings: Add a copy files phase and add this framework to the   'Frameworks' folder in copy file phase.

Comment: While creating a copy files phase solves it, if the framework is already in the Embed Frameworks, it already means that Xcode will copy it to the Frameworks folder. Using the copy files phase with the framework option is usually used for frameworks that are built outside Xcode, i.e. command line tool.