# Swift: App Installation Failed Could Not Inspect The Application Package (When Using Frameworks with XCode 6)

Tags: xcode, swift, frameworks, xcode6, cocoapods

I'm having difficulties running a compiled app on an iPhone 6 (iOS8). **It works fine in the simulator.**

I get this error message:

```
App installation failed
Could not inspect the application package
```

Originally there were error messages - such as the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26058980/swift-ios-module-not-being-deployed-to-expected-debug-directory) but I fixed this temporarily by moving the output into the correct location. However even though all of the libraries are being codesign'ed correctly and are now found I am unable to use the app on my device.

There seems to be no further error messages and therefore no way of debugging anything. How exactly do normal iOS developers debug problems which give no error messages?

I guess the underlying problem is that my project is getting quite complex, there are a lot of moving pieces: a few cocoapods, Alamofire, ReactiveCocoa, and Moya.

I have a few general questions:

1. Where can I find information that documents the use of frameworks in XCode 6?
2. What is the difference between "Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries", "Build Phases -> Copy Files", "General -> Embedded Binaries" and "General -> Linked Frameworks and Libraries"?
3. Everything is compiling completely fine for the simulator, including the cocoapods, but I note that there are libPod.a files and wonder whether they need to be compiled into the app?
4. Mostly I am hoping to find some way of finding out why the application package can't be inspected. Surely whatever software that inspects this must be able to be debugged?!!

**Edit:**

For the record, (1) there is no file called Resources in the root folder as I get nothing back when I do this "find . -name Resources" so it cannot be that issue, (2) I have run "Product -> Clean" and then tried to build again and this does not solve the problem either, (3) the Info.plist does contain a CFBundleName which is set to "${PRODUCT_NAME}" currently (which I believe is set elsewhere.)

Comment: The documentation on this stuff really sucks... :(

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this. I am not sure exactly what the solution was, but effectively what I did was to remove all of the cocoapods, detach all of the extra projects that were being used to compile frameworks, and then completely clean the build folder (by holding Alt while going to Product > Clean.)

I then added each of the frameworks back and made sure that each of them would compile.

I checked the build output and near the bottom of each I was able to find the location in which the frameworks were being built.

I then went back to the parent app, and was able to change the framework search paths to include the folders that the frameworks were being built in.

I may have changed a couple of other paths, too, though I cannot remember completely.

I think that basically the issue was a combination of (1) a very dirty build path, (2) leftover files and bad configuration causing issues, (3) frameworks being built in the wrong location.

Answer (score 0):

check your "Copy Bundle Resources",delete info.plist if it contained.
It's work for me in Xcode 6.4