# Xcode 6 Embedded Binaries

Tags: ios, xcode, git, jenkins

We are building an iOS 8 app on Xcode 6.1 that has the following project structure -

- UI (Git Repo 1)
- Framework (Git Repo 2)

Git Repo 2 is added as a submodule to Git Repo 1. The framework project is listed as a "Embedded Binary" under the UI project. We have a couple of problems with this -

- The embedded binaries' path is specific to a developer's machine and every developer has to update the path after pulling the latest code from the repo.

  - If the path above is specific to a particular machine how can we build the code on Jenkins?

Is there a better approach to handle the above situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define your embedded binaries to be Relative to Build Products, then it doesn't matter what the dev's directory structures look like. This enables you to use Jenkins as you wish.

For one of the projects I'm working on, we are using a workspace versus sub-projects since our different libraries are different git repos than the application itself.

Although this is for swift, this link describes a bit about using the Relative To Build Products.

[Swift iOS module not being deployed to expected debug directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26058980/swift-ios-module-not-being-deployed-to-expected-debug-directory/27614914#27614914)

Comment: Thanks Ben. I followed the directions in the link you provided and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Our team ended up independently coming to the same conclusion as you Ben, but I awarded you the bounty anyway. Thanks!